# Open .docx with Apache POI and save it with password

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

The goal is to open existing .docx document and save it encrypted with password.
I use Apache POI library for that. The code below works fine and makes document encrypted and password protected.

But after the file creating I can open it with the LibreOffice but can't with the MS Word or OpenOffice Writer.

It seems that the file has no content type part cuz OpenOffice asked me about file's filter. But when I choosed "Microsoft Word 2007 XML" I got the "Common Input-Output error" from the OpenOffice

Could I ask you to help me with it, guys?
P.S.
I use Java 8 and POI 3.17

```
    static boolean encryptOne(String documentPath, String password) {
    try {
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();

        EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
        Encryptor encryptor = info.getEncryptor();
        encryptor.confirmPassword(password);

        OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(documentPath), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
        opc.save(encryptor.getDataStream(fs));
        opc.close();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(documentPath);
        fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
        fos.close();

        System.out.println("Document successfully encrypted");

        return true;

    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException | InvalidFormatException e) {
        ExceptionPrinter.printOutStream(e);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me when used https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XML-based+formats+-+Encryption code and the encrypted `*.docx` can be opened using Word 2007 in Windows 7 and Word 365 in Windows 10 and WPS Writer in Windows 7 and Libreoffice Writer in Ubuntu as well. OpenOffice Writer may have problems but creating files for OO Writer is not the goal of  `apache poi`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alex. My code based on this example too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved the problem by changing EncryptionMode:

```
// EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.standard);
```

I found some information that free (no pay) versions of the MS Word don't support ECMA-376.Agile encryption. So, I changed encryption mode to ECMA-376.Standard and it works for me. 
I'm not sure that it's true but it helped in my case.

Hope this will help someone.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "free (no pay) versions of the MS Word" mean? Microsoft Word Online cannot using encrypted documents at all.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find the article with this info. But I think that it means trial (for 1 month) version of the MS Word or it's preview version, I used trial version when faced this problem.